# How to use or in ifelse statement in R?

Tags: r

I am using the below code its not working .Y has 2 levels (the or function doesnt work ).whats the solution ?

```
data$Team1=factor(data$Team1)

y=levels(data$Team1)

data$win_loss=ifelse(data$winner==y[2]|y[1], "winner",
              ifelse(data$winner==is.na(data$winner),"noresult","looser"))
```

sample data
Team1   winner  win/loss
x1        x1    x1
x1        x1    x1
x2        x3    x3
x1        x1    x1
x1        x4    x4
x1        x1    x1
x1        NA    NA
x1        NA    NA

I want win/loss column based on Team1 and winner.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data, so we can see where the error comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1

Use `data$winner` on the other side of your OR operation.

```
data$Team1=factor(data$Team1)

y=levels(data$Team1)

data$win_loss=ifelse(data$winner==y[2] | data$winner==y[1], "winner",
              ifelse(is.na(data$winner),"noresult","loser"))
```

## Option 2

Call the vector `y[1:2]` and use the `%in%` operator.

```
data$Team1=factor(data$Team1)

y=levels(data$Team1)

data$win_loss=ifelse(data$winner %in% y[1:2], "winner",
              ifelse(is.na(data$winner),"noresult","loser"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two steps to keep it simple:

```
# replace NA
data$Team1[is.na(data$Team1)] <- 'noresult'

# replace other values
data$Team1 <- ifelse(data$Team1 %in% levels(data$Team1), 'winner', 'loser')
```